# Power calibration - battery level drops suddenly in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, shutdown, battery, charging

I shifted to ubuntu 20.04 from windows 8 . Now I have some problems with my battery.

1. When it is around 20% it immediately drops to 5-6% and then shut down
2. I charged it to 100% but as soon as I remove the plug it goes to 91-92%

I had tried `power-calibrate  -R -r 20 -d 5 -s 21 -n 0 -p` but nothing changed.